# Wait for thread queue to be empty

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am new to C++ and multithreading applications. I want to process a long list of data (potentially several thousands of entries) by dividing its entries among a few threads. I have retrieved a ThreadPool class and a Queue class from the web (it is my first time tackling the subject). I construct the threads and populate the queue in the following way (definitions at the end of the post):

```
ThreadPool *pool = new ThreadPool(8);
std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> *caller = 
    new std::vector<std::function<void(int)>>;
for (size_t i = 0; i < Nentries; ++i)
{
    caller->push_back( 
        [=](int j){func(entries[i], j);});
    pool->PushTask((*caller)[i]);
}
delete pool;
```

The problem is that only a number of entries equaling the number of created threads are processed, as if the program does not wait for the queue to be empty. Indeed, if I put

```
while (pool->GetWorkQueueLength()) {}
```

just before the pool destructor, the whole list is correctly processed. However, I am afraid I am consuming too many resources by using a while loop. Moreover, I have not found anyone doing anything like it, so I think this is the wrong approach and the classes I use have some error. Can anyone find the error (if present) or suggest another solution?

Here are the classes I use. I suppose the problem is in the implementation of the destructor, but I am not sure.

SynchronizeQueue.hh

```
#ifndef SYNCQUEUE_H
#define SYNCQUEUE_H
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template<typename T>
class SynchronizedQueue
{
    public:
        SynchronizedQueue();

        void Put(T const & data);
        T Get();
        size_t Size();

    private:
        SynchronizedQueue(SynchronizedQueue const &)=delete;
        SynchronizedQueue & operator=(SynchronizedQueue const &)=delete;

        std::list<T> queue;
        std::mutex mut;
        std::condition_variable condvar;
};

template<typename T>
SynchronizedQueue<T>::SynchronizedQueue()
{}


template<typename T>
void SynchronizedQueue<T>::Put(T const & data)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    queue.push_back(data);
    condvar.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
T SynchronizedQueue<T>::Get()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    while (queue.empty())
    {
        condvar.wait(lck);
    }
    T result = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
size_t SynchronizedQueue<T>::Size()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    return queue.size();
}

#endif
```

ThreadPool.hh

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H    
#include "SynchronizedQueue.hh"
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class ThreadPool
{
    public:
        ThreadPool(int nThreads = 0);
        virtual ~ThreadPool();

        void PushTask(std::function<void(int)> func);

        size_t GetWorkQueueLength();

    private:
        void WorkerThread(int i);

        std::atomic<bool> done;
        unsigned int threadCount;
        SynchronizedQueue<std::function<void(int)>> workQueue;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

#endif
```

ThreadPool.cc

```
#include "ThreadPool.hh"
#include "SynchronizedQueue.hh"

void doNothing(int i)
{}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int nThreads)
    : done(false)
{
    if (nThreads <= 0)
    {
        threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    } 
    else
    {
        threadCount = nThreads;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::WorkerThread, this, i));
    }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    done = true;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
        PushTask(&doNothing);
    }
    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}

void ThreadPool::PushTask(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    workQueue.Put(func);
}

void ThreadPool::WorkerThread(int i)
{
    while (!done)
    {
        workQueue.Get()(i);
    }
}

size_t ThreadPool::GetWorkQueueLength()
{
    return workQueue.Size();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but better add `lck.unlock()` before `condvar.notify_one();` So that after being notified, the other end ready to lock mutex. Lack of this `unlock` does not affect correctness, but may affect performance

Answer (score 0):

> I want to process a long list of data (potentially several thousands of entries) by dividing its entries among a few threads.

You can do that with parallel algorithms, like [`tbb::parallel_for`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506153):

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <vector>

void func(int entry);

int main () {
    std::vector<int> entries(1000000);
    tbb::parallel_for(size_t{0}, entries.size(), [&](size_t i) { func(entries[i]); });
}
```

If you need sequential thread ids, you can do:

```
void func(int element, int thread_id);

template<class C>
inline auto make_range(C& c) -> decltype(tbb::blocked_range<decltype(c.begin())>(c.begin(), c.end())) {
    return tbb::blocked_range<decltype(c.begin())>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> entries(1000000);
    std::atomic<int> thread_counter{0};
    tbb::parallel_for(make_range(entries), [&](auto sub_range) {
        static thread_local int const thread_id = thread_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        for(auto& element : sub_range)
            func(element, thread_id);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, there is [`std::this_thread::get_id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id).

Comment: Is it possible to keep track of which thread does what with this method? For example, making so that data processed by thread number N are saved in file_N?

Comment: @Rdat Added an example for you.

Comment: parallel `for_each` is C++17 already. So use of 3rd party library might not be really needed. Anyway, I think fixing author's code is more helpful for threading understanding than suggesting out-of-box implementation.

Comment: @Rdat, If I wanted each of N different threads to save data to its own designated file, I would give each thread a _delegate_ (i.e., an object) that is responsible for knowing where and how to save the data. Any time I see code that needs to know the identity of the thread that runs it, I consider that to be a [code smell](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html). That is, a "feature" of the program that could lead to future bugs or future maintenance headaches.

Comment: I understand that C++17 has built-in parallel support for some functions. However, as the tag of my post suggests, my code is in C++11.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev [Only 3 compilers support C++17 Parallelism TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) as of today. g++ supports it starting with version 9 and it actually delegates to Intel TBB. Intel TBB is more portable because it works in C++11 and with more and older compilers.

Comment: I see. MSVC has its own, and so for my purposes I would prefer MSVC just to avoid another library dependency (obtaining, license approval, etc). Didn't assume that it may be different for other compilers

Answer (score 0):

You can push tasks saying "done" instead of setting "done" via atomic variable.

So that each thread will exit by itself when seeing "done" task, and no earlier. In destructor you only need to push these tasks and join threads. This is called ["poison pill"](https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/22-queues/#stopping).

Alternatively, if you insist on your current design with `done` variable, you can wait on the same condition you already have:

```
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        condvar.wait(lck);
    }
```

But then you'll need to change your `notify_one` to `notify_all`, and this may be sub-optimal.

Comment: FYI: The "done" task that you're talking about sometimes is known as a _[poison pill](https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/22-queues/#stopping)_.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, thanks, I've edited answer. (I'll also consider editing code where I re-invented this pattern without knowing its name, to refer some known thing)